# Every even degree polynomial is eventually symmetric

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, polynomials

Let  we have  a  polynomial function $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $F(x)=ax^{2n}+bx^{2n-1}+\ldots+px+q$.

We assume  that $a>0$. For    sufficiently large $y$,  let  $A(y), B(y)$ be two distinct right inverses of  $F$, that  is  $F(A(y))=F(B(y))=y$ please see     [the picture of this  linked page](https://qr.ae/T6hAkl)

**Prove that**  **$$\lim_{y\to{\infty}} A(y)+B(y)=-b/na$$**

> I  had  and I  have a  proof  for  this exercise but  I am searching for  some  other proofs or some other elementary proofs. Moreover   I wish to check and examine  whether it is really a very trivial elementary exercise or it is a bit nontrivial. Note that for  higher degrees, according to Galois, we have  no  a  precise  formula for $A(y)$ and  $B(y)$.
>
> **Pleease see page 4, item III line  $-3$ of    my paper  below.** The journal who accepted my paper (year 2002), did not  asked me to provide any  proof. Regarding this  *limit*, inside the paper below I wrote that  "it is a simple  exercise". I did not write any proof of this *limit* in my thesis. No one in my defense committee asked me any proof of this *limit*. After all I think that it is  quite easy to proof. Thought it is  a  very simple  limit but playt a  crucial role to determine the  stability of  the  homoclinic loop based at equattor of Poincare sphere:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409594.pdf

**RemarK:** This  actualy gives us some information on the  sum of  complex  preimages $F^{-1}(y) \subset \mathbb{C}$ as $y$ goes to $\infty$. On the other hand, [inspired by this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46068/how-small-can-a-sum-of-a-few-roots-of-unity-be) one may think to upper and  lower bound on  the norm of  subsets of $F^{-1}(y)$

Comment: Please show what you have so far, otherwise people might waste their time finding the same proof that you did.

Comment: @CardboardBox  To  be  honnest I prefer to not do that. because I was  very  surprized why no body(editires, referee,...etc,..) has no  any reflection on this.The proof is really easy but I prefer to not share it. So if  some  one  is  interested in this  question, he/she  can think about it. even if  his/her answer is the same  as mine, he  did not wast his  time because Thinking to  a  mathematical problem which one  like it, is  never  a  wast of  time"

Comment: @ViktorGlombik  I can not say that it is a  secret because the proof is very easy. But I just want to test wether it is realy a trivial subject. However according to a  post of  terry Tao in MO such kind of  question can help us to study the  sum of  complex roots of  a  real polynomial mequation. I can not  find  the link of  Tao  post, I read it some ytears ago. Any way it is  not a secret but please read my previous comment. I submited this paperr to a journal to receive my Ph.D

Comment: @ViktorGlombik  can you help me to find that  link of  question by Terry  Tao?(it  has  a  larg  amount of reputation and view). it was about  the  sum of  complex  number of  level sets of a real polynomial but unfortunately I do not  remember that link

Comment: What if $n=1$, $a=1$, $b=0$, $q=0$, $A(y)=B(y)=\sqrt{y}$, then we have $\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty} A(y)+B(y) = \infty$ right?

Comment: @JensWagemaker  $B(y)=-\sqrt{y}$. Agree?

Comment: @JensWagemaker  please see the picture  https://qr.ae/T6hAkl

Comment: @Ali Taghavi, you didn't say that $A$ and $B$ had to be distinct. But in that case indeed $A(y)=\sqrt{y}$ and $B(y)=-\sqrt{y}$. And the statement holds.

Comment: @JensWagemaker yes you are right i add "distinct" thanks.

Comment: Your problem is quite interesting but something difficult. I have studied the case $b=0$ and one can see that for $y$ large enough (greater than the global maximum) the resulting equation has two real roots whose sum tends to zero according to your problem. It seems the key of the question is first to prove that $x_1+x_2$ is decreasing till $\dfrac{-b}{na}$. But it is not easy.

Comment: @CardboardBox Please see the updated version of  my question. Thank you!

Comment: Answering your question above, your problem is by no means an elementary exercise (if it were, you should have already had several answers). In my opinion it is a question worth presenting in a paper.

Comment: I think you should also post your own solution once you have got a variety of answers here and you feel satisfied with some of them.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  Yes. I  write immediate after I understand all answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  My solution is  based on application of "intermediate  value theorem"

Comment: Well there is no need to hurry here. Feel free to post when you think it is appropriate.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  No  I can write it now  then I read the  details of  all answer. Please read my answer up to 5 minute

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I just wrote the solution. I would like to thank your attention to my question and  your answer.

Comment: @Piquito  I think that its  generalization to higher dimension is interesting and is  possibly worth of  research paper. Please see the  comment conversation to Paramanand Singh's  answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's replace $A(y), B(y) $ by $A, B$ to simplify typing and let $A>0>B$ and we write $C=-B$ so that $C>0$. Then we have $$y=aA^{2n}+bA^{2n-1}+\dots$$ and $$y=aC^{2n}-bC^{2n-1}+\dots$$ From these equations we get $$y/A^{2n}\to a, y/C^{2n}\to a$$ so that $A/C\to 1$.

Subtracting these equations we get $$a(A^{2n}-C^{2n})+b(A^{2n-1}+C^{2n-1})+\dots=0$$ or $$a(A-C) (A^{2n-1}+A^{2n-2}C+\dots+C^{2n-1})+b(A^{2n-1}+C^{2n-1})+\dots =0$$ Dividing the above equation by $C^{2n-1}$ we get $$a(A-C)\{1+(A/C)+(A/C)^2+\dots+(A/C)^{2n-1}\} +b\{1+(A/C)^{2n-1}\} + \text{ (terms tending to zero)} =0$$ Letting $y\to \infty $ in above equation we get $$2na\lim_{y\to\infty} (A-C) +2b=0$$ or $$A-C\to-\frac{b} {na} $$ as $y\to\infty $.

One has to observe that when we divide by $C^{2n-1}$ the terms like $A^{r} / C^{2n-1}$ tend to $0$ for $r<2n-1$ because we can write it as $(A/C) ^r(C^r/C^{2n-1})$.

---

The argument above is entirely elementary and simple. We just have to understand that $A, C$ are functions of $y$ which are strictly increasing as $y\to\infty $ and $$A\to\infty, C\to\infty, A/C\to 1$$ as $y\to\infty $. Further they satisfy the relation $F(A) =y=F(-C) $.

In general most of the algebraic limits do not involve anything more algebraic manipulation.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. a  possible  generalization could be  the following: consider the  polynomial   $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+ax+by+c$. For each $z\in \mathbb{R}$ put $p_z=\text{the centroied of } f^{-1}(z)$.  This  centroid  is in the plane. Does there exist a  limit for $p_z$?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: the curve $f(x, y) =z$ is a circle and it's centroid should be $(-a/2,-b/2,z) $. Do you mean this or something different.

Comment: You are completely  right This  case was obvious. But I mean that we generalize to higher dimension via  generalized paraboloid. I remember I presented this  question somewhere, here or MO  or  RG  or Quora(I dont remember exactly. The  question is the following

Comment: Let we  have  a polynomial f  whose last  homogenious part is a well behaved homogenious  polynomial In this  case can we  generalize this  result  vioa  centroid in R^2?

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  sounds interesting. You should put this as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

If $A(y)>0$, such that 
$$
a\big(A(y)\big)^{2n}+b\big(A(y)\big)^{2n-1}+\cdots+q=y, \tag{1}
$$
then $A(y)\to\infty$, as $yas\to\infty$, and hence $\big(A(y)\big)^{2n}\gg \big(A(y)\big)^{2n-1}$. So from $(1)$ we obtain $A(y)\approx\Big(\frac{y}{a}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2n}}$. In particular, there exists a function $e_+(y)$, such that
$$
A(y)=\Big(\frac{y}{a}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2n}}+e_+(y), \quad |e_+(y)|\ll y^\frac{1}{2n}.
$$
To get a better estimate for $e_+$, we have
$$
a\bigg(\Big(\frac{y}{a}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2n}}+e_+(y)\bigg)^{2n}+b\bigg(\Big(\frac{y}{a}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2n}}+e_+(y)\bigg)^{2n-1}+\cdots+q=y,
$$
or
$$
\bigg(y+2na\Big(\frac{y}{a}\Big)^{\frac{2n-1}{2n}}e_+(y)+\frac{2n(2n-1)}{2}a\Big(\frac{y}{a}\Big)^{\frac{2n-2}{2n}}e_+^2(y)+\cdots\bigg)+\bigg(b\Big(\frac{y}{a}\Big)^{\frac{2n-1}{2n}}+b\Big(\frac{y}{a}\Big)^{\frac{2n-2}{2n}}e_+(y)+\cdots\bigg)\\+\cdots+q=y.
$$
The assumption $|e_+(y)|\ll y^\frac{1}{2n}$ implies now that
$$
e_+(y)=-\frac{b}{2an}+d_+(y)
$$
where $\lim_{y\to\infty} d_+(y)=0$.

Repeating this argument for $B(y)<0$, with
$$
a\big(B(y)\big)^{2n}+b\big(B(y)\big)^{2n-1}+\cdots+q=y,
$$
we obtain that 
$$
B(y)=-\Big(\frac{y}{a}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2n}}+e_-(y), \quad |e_+(y)|\ll y^\frac{1}{2n}.
$$
and similarly we obtain that
$$
e_-(y)=-\frac{b}{2an}+d_-(y)
$$
where $\lim_{y\to\infty} d_-(y)=0$.

Hence
$$
A(y)+B(y)=-\frac{b}{na}+d_-(y)+d_+(y)\to -\frac{b}{na}.
$$

Comment: Very good. Then, except for subtle error, the question can be answered by elementary means.

Comment: @Piquito  As  I said in the question, the limit is very elementary. I wrote  a  short solution too. please see my answer(and the  updated title)

Comment: Thank you very much for  your  answer and your  attention to my question.I wrote a  short answer, too.

Comment: Thank you again  for  your  answer. I am sorry I can not accept several answers simultaneously https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1491/why-cant-i-accept-two-answers-to-the-same-question-simultaneously

Answer (score 3):

It is clear that $A(y), B(y) \sim \pm (y/a)^{1/2n}$, and the problem is to determine the lower order term in their expansion. Wlog suppose $B(y) < 0 < A(y)$. By the mean value theorem,
$$(A(y) - (y/a)^{1/2n}) \cdot F'(\xi) \sim y - F((y/a)^{1/2n}) \,,$$
for some $\xi \sim (y/a)^{1/2n}$.
The LHS is $\sim 2an \cdot (y/a)^{(2n-1)/2n}$ times what we are looking for, and the RHS is $b(y/a)^{(2n-1)/2n} (1 + o(1))$. We conclude that
$$A(y) - (y/a)^{1/2n} \sim \frac{b}{2an} \,.$$
Replacing $F(x)$ by $F(-x)$, we obtain
$$-B(y) - (y/a)^{1/2n} \sim \frac{-b}{2an} \,.$$
The conclusion follows.

Comment: Thank you for  your  answer. I am sorry I can not accept several answers simultaneously https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1491/why-cant-i-accept-two-answers-to-the-same-question-simultaneously

Answer (score 2):

**Proof**: It is  sufficient to prove the result when $b=0$. Otherwise we set the  change  of  variable $x:=x-b/2na$ to obtain a polynomial with $b=0$.

Assume that $b=0$. Then for  every given   $\epsilon>0$ if  $x>0$ is  sufficiently large we have $F(x-\epsilon)<F(-x)<F(x+\epsilon)$. Now  apply intermediate value theorem. Putting $y=F(-x)$ we have $B(y)=-x$ now intermediate value theorem implies $x-\epsilon< A(y)<x+\epsilon$  thus  $-\epsilon<A(y)+B(y)<\epsilon$. **Q.E.D**

> As we said in the  question, despite of  its  simplicity, this  *limit* played a  crucial role  to prove the main result of the paper( stability of the  homoclinic  loop under consideration of the paper). But this *limit* was not questioned any where, neither by the journal nor by defense committee, etc.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-Let $F_n(x)$ defined as in your problem
$$F_n(x)=ax^{2n}+bx^{2n-1}+cx^{2n-2}+dx^{2n-3}\ldots+px+q$$ Assuming $c\ne0$ one has 
$$F_n(x)=ax^{2n}+bx^{2n-1}\pm F_{n-1}(x)\hspace{10mm}(*)$$ (the sign $+$ when $c$ is positive and the sign $-$ when $c$ is negative).

Besides the property is easily verified for $n=1$. In fact $$F_1(x)=ax^2+bx+c\Rightarrow a(x_1^2-x_2^2)+b(x_1-x_2)=0\Rightarrow x_1+x_2=\frac{-b}{a}$$

Can you now apply induction in any way using the equation $(*)$?

Comment: Thank you very much for  your  attention to my question. To  be  honest I do not see how can we get the result with induction.

Comment: You are welcome. It may not be possible in effect by induction. I thought of such a possibility by the exposed form.

Comment: Please  see my  comment to Paramanand Singh's  answer. My comment is  suggesting a  generalization to higher dimension